# Reverse $\displaystyle v(t)=R\,i(t)+L\,\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}\,\int_0^ti(\tau)\,d\tau$ as function of current $i(t)$?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, differential-equations, inductance

Consider the electrical circuit equation written as
$$v(t)=R\,i(t)+L\,\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}\,\int_0^ti(\tau)\,d\tau \tag{1}$$
where $v(t)$ is electrical potential, $i(t)$ is current, $R$ is electrical resistance, $L$ is inductance and $C$ is electric capacitance. $R$, $C$ and $L$ are non-null constants.

I can rewrite it like
$$v(t)=\mathcal H[i(t)]$$
where $\mathcal H[\,\cdot\,]$ is some linear differential operator which generates the formula above.

---

**Question**

Is there a way to achieve
$$i(t)=\mathcal H^{-1}[v(t)]$$
such that
$$\mathcal H^{-1}[v(t)]=\mathcal Y[v(t)]$$
where $\mathcal Y[\,\cdot\,]$ is again a linear differential operator, so that some sort 'reversal' of eq. (1) is obtained?

**Note**: 'Reversal' aims to relate current $i(t)$ to derivatives of voltage $v(t)$, instead of the usual opposite given by eq. (1)

**Note**: An example for what i aim $\mathcal Y[\,\cdot\,]$ to be like, is
$$i(t)=\mathcal Y[v(t)]=A\,v(t)+B\,\frac{dv(t)}{dt}+D\,\int_0^t v(\tau)\,d\tau\tag{2}$$

Comment: Can we assume $C,\,L,\,R$ are constants with $C\ne0,\,L\ne0$?

Comment: Yes, i should add, thanks

Comment: After reasoning a bit, i'm starting to think that there's no such thing as 'eq. (1) reversal', as any reversal coincides inevitably with solving the ODE.. Also @J.G. answer, using Fourier transform is eventually a way to achieve that result. Result that nevertheless is a integro-differential operator itself..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being physicists, we should give [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) a try. Given$$\begin{align}L\ddot{i}+R\dot{i}+i/C&=\dot{v}(t)\\&=\int_\mathbb{R}\delta(t-t^\prime)\dot{v}(t^\prime)dt^\prime\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R^2}\exp[iw(t-t^\prime)]\dot{v}(t^\prime)dt^\prime dw,\end{align}$$we have a solution$$i(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R^2}\frac{\exp[iw(t-t^\prime)]\dot{v}(t^\prime)}{-w^2L+iwR+1/C}dt^\prime dw.$$Of course, (i) the differentiation I started with introduces fake solutions in which $v$ picks up an additive constant, & (ii) the "solution" above isn't exhaustive for the fake-solutions-included problem variant. But if you want a linear operator on $v$, this is a good start; we've found what is technically know as an *integro-differential operator*. That's unsurprising, considering we started with an [integro-differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integro-differential_equation).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, only thing is that we are introducing an additional variable $w$

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta Yes, but it's a dummy variable.

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta The (original) text of the question specifies a linear operator; the expression in this answer statisfies it completely. The concrete form of $\mathcal Y$ you quote in the edit (v6) is unrealistic. Once you differentiate as in this answer (to get a 2nd-order ODE in terms of $\dot v$) you are inverting a differential operator, so you should expect an integral operator anyway. For the general theory, see any textbook on differential equations.

Comment: (... though, that said, the Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(-L\omega^2 + i R \omega +1/C\right)^{-1} e^{i\omega \tau}\mathrm d\omega$ can be integrated explicitly and fully analytically in terms of elementary functions, using either a partial-fraction decomposition or the method of residues. This won't be the case in general but for the simple ODE here it does work.)

Comment: Integration is perfectly fine, and no problem with this answer, to which went my upvote and sincere thanks. With last edit i didn't varied the question in any detail, but made it more clear. Example provided in question is clearly wrong, in fact it just wants to be an idea. Didn't select this as best answer yet, since i'm waiting for a simple answer without additional variables in the final form, if can be the case. Or other possible methods to compare.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
Differentiating the equation once will result in a secon order ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients, which is easily solvable by standard methods.

**Method 2**
Using Laplace transform allows to express the Laplace image of $i$ in terms of the Laplace image of $v$, and the reverse transform gives the required solution.

Comment: No it doesn't, my question is about reversing the formula.. not about solving it

Comment: @GiorgioPastasciutta Laplace transform is probably even better - I added it to my answer.

Comment: If you solve for $i(t)$ in terms of $v(t)$ it is the same as reversing the formula. Though I cannot guarantee that it will have the form that youproposed - I didn't do the math.

Comment: Yes, that wanted to be an example. The goal is a linear differential operator (like $\mathcal H$ is), I have to state it more appropriately

Comment: You can always reverse a linear differential operator in terms of its eigenfunctions. Look up also *Greens function*.

Comment: After a rapid check on math.se, it appears that eigenfunctions solve the $L[f]=\lambda\,f$ problem, with $L[\,\cdot\,]$ diff. operator, but how this can be of help about my question?

Comment: Green's function is the inverse operator, and it can be expressed in terms of the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.